# VueJS BPagination - calls my method multiple times everytime it changes the currentPage

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this:

```
<template>
 <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
     <b-pagination
          v-model="currentPage"
          :total-rows="totalRows"
          :per-page="perPage"
      />
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  data : function () {
        return {
            images: [],
            isLoadingImage: true,
            loadingText: "Please wait while we're loading the images...",
            searchText : '',
            currentPage: 1,
            totalRows: 16,
            perPage: 50,
        }
  },

  watch : {
     currentPage (to, from) {
        this.searchImage();
     },
  },

  mounted() {
      this.searchImage();
  },

  methods : {
     searchImage() {
        let _this = this;
        this.isLoadingImage = true;
        MyCustomService.showImage(this.searchText,this.currentPage).then(function(result){
                _this.isLoadingImage = false;
                _this.images = result.data.results;
                _this.totalRows = result.data.page.totalitems;
                _this.perPage = result.data.page.itemsperpage;
        });
     }
  }
</script>
```

I noticed that when I clicked the numbers on the pagination, this one:

[image]

It calls the `searchImage()` twice. So when i wanted to go to page 2, so that makes the `currentPage` = `2`, it goes to page `2` then it resets back to `1`.

BTW - the `MyCustomService.showImage()` is an `async` function, not sure if that gives you an additional info.

Why is that? I think my code is very straight forward but i am getting this strange result.

Let me know if you need further clarification and i'm happy to add some information.

Thanks and your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In your `watch.currentPage` before calling `this.searchImage()` add an if where you compare the `to` and `from`:
`if(to !== from) this.searchImage()`

Comment: I think it may be caused by `_this.perPage = result.data.page.itemsperpage;`. I create a fiddle for this https://jsfiddle.net/34qzv87L/. And from source code https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/src/components/pagination/pagination.js#L64.